# NSwag (Command-Line OR Studio) not generating Swagger from Assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, nswag

**Problem:**
I wish to generate a Swagger file (Open API document) from an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API project (either from the solution file or Compiled assemblies).

Everything is tried using the [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag) tools.

---

**Setup**
I've installed NSwag studio so "nswag" command is directly available from Command prompt. I've also built using the following way as [recommended](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/Assembly-loading#net-core):

```
dotnet build /p:CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies=true
```

---

**Error: Command Line**

The error I get after using **AspNetCore2OpenApi** command is:

```
Command: aspnetcore2openapi /assembly:TestApi.dll /documentName:OpenApi3 /output:swagger.json

System.InvalidOperationException: The command 'aspnetcore2openapi /assembly:testapi.dll /documentname:openapi3 /output:swagger.json' could not be found.
   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.<ProcessSingleAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.<ProcessAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.Process(String[] args, Object input)
   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagCommandProcessor.Process(String[] args)
```

---

**Error:NSwagStudio**

[image: This is my setup]

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Runtime: NetCore22
   at CatalogApi.Extensions.HttpClientPolicyExtensions.AddPolicies(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) in C:\Users\ansiddiq\Source\Repos\SS-ME-ES-APIC-CatalogService\Api\CatalogApi\Extensions\HttpClientPolicyExtensions.cs:line 36
   at CatalogApi.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Users\ansiddiq\Source\Repos\SS-ME-ES-APIC-CatalogService\Api\CatalogApi\Startup.cs:line 102
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.OpenApiGeneratorCommandBase`1.CreateWebHostAsync(AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Generation\OpenApiGeneratorCommandBase.cs:line 318
   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToSwaggerCommand.RunIsolatedAsync(AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Generation\AspNetCore\AspNetCoreToOpenApiCommand.cs:line 309
   at NSwag.Commands.IsolatedCommandBase`1.IsolatedCommandAssemblyLoader`1.Run(String commandType, String commandData, String[] assemblyPaths, String[] referencePaths) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\IsolatedCommandBase.cs:line 71
   at NSwag.Commands.IsolatedCommandBase`1.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<RunIsolatedAsync>b__0() in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\IsolatedCommandBase.cs:line 61
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at NSwag.Commands.IsolatedCommandBase`1.RunIsolatedAsync(String configurationFile)
   at NSwag.Commands.IsolatedSwaggerOutputCommandBase`1.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\IsolatedSwaggerOutputCommandBase.cs:line 47
   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToSwaggerCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Generation\AspNetCore\AspNetCoreToOpenApiCommand.cs:line 94
   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocumentBase.GenerateSwaggerDocumentAsync() in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\NSwagDocumentBase.cs:line 279
   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocument.ExecuteAsync() in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\NSwagDocument.cs:line 81
   at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.ExecuteDocumentAsync(IConsoleHost host, String filePath) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Document\ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 85
   at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Document\ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 32
   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessSingleAsync(String[] args, Object input)
   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessAsync(String[] args, Object input)
   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.Process(String[] args, Object input)
   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagCommandProcessor.Process(String[] args) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\NSwagCommandProcessor.cs:line 56
```

This error seems to be in a file where I use "[Polly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly/2.2.0/)" library in Middleware for HTTP Retry logic. There is no problem in the code as it compiles/runs fine.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please reference github issue.

Comment: Sure, the discussion is being tracked here - https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2265